# Django changes pub_date when I do .save()

Tags: python, django, pubdate

I have a model Question with an IntegerField named flags and a datetime Field called pub_date. pub_date is set to be auto_now=True.
I have a view for changing the flags field. And when I change the flags and do .save() to the Question object, its pub date changes to now. 
I wan't the pub_date to be set only when it's being created and not when I'm changing some data in the record. How can I do this? 
If you need to see my code, please tell me because I don't think you need to here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should set `auto_now_add = True`

Comment: Just be aware that setting auto_now_add = True will will cause the field to have editable=False and blank=True set.

Answer (score 2):

You can just  remove auto_now=True and set the field manually when you want to, in your view.